# how can i detect the direction of scrolling when it is on ThumbTrack mode

Tags: c#

I have an issue using vertical scroll bar,, when it is on thumbTrack mode, i don't know if it goes up or down , so how can i detect the direction of scrolling when it is on ThumbTrack mode
here is the code:

```
    private void vScrollBar_ShowAll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {

        bool b_allow = false;

        if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
        {
            if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement)
            {
                if (ControlIndex < ToIndex){ ControlIndex++;b_allow = true;}
            }

            else if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement)
            {
                if (ControlIndex > FromIndex) { ControlIndex--; b_allow = true; }

            }
            else if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement)
            {
                if (ControlIndex < ToIndex) { ControlIndex += 10; b_allow = true; }
            }
            else if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement)
            {
                if (ControlIndex > FromIndex) { ControlIndex -= 10; b_allow = true; }
            }
            else if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition)
            {
                if (ControlIndex > FromIndex) { ControlIndex -= 10; b_allow = true; }
            }
            else if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack)
            {

                if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue)
                    if (ControlIndex < ToIndex) { ControlIndex += 10; b_allow = true; }
                else
                if (ControlIndex > FromIndex) { ControlIndex -= 10; b_allow = true; }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in your `e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack` branch where you compare `e.NewValue` and `e.OldValue`. looks to be sufficient. Remember that a vertical scroll bar's position (the `.Value` property) [starts with its minimum value at the top and goes down to its maximum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#scroll_position_and_range).

I quickly through together a Windows Forms application with a vertical scroll bar. Here's the code that I have in my `Scroll` event handler:

```cs
private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {
    Debug.WriteLine(e.ScrollOrientation.ToString());

    if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack) {
        if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue) {
            Debug.WriteLine("down");
        } else if (e.NewValue < e.OldValue) {
            Debug.WriteLine("up");
        } else {
            Debug.WriteLine("stay");
        }
    } else {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Type.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here's the debug spew I get when I click and drag down:

```
VerticalScroll
stay
VerticalScroll
down
VerticalScroll
down
VerticalScroll
ThumbPosition
VerticalScroll
EndScroll
```

Here's the spew when I drag up:

```
VerticalScroll
stay
VerticalScroll
up
VerticalScroll
up
VerticalScroll
ThumbPosition
VerticalScroll
EndScroll
```

And, if I start dragging down and then change to up:

```
VerticalScroll
stay
VerticalScroll
down
VerticalScroll
up
VerticalScroll
up
VerticalScroll
ThumbPosition
VerticalScroll
EndScroll
```